# What is Big O amortization?

Tags: c++, big-o

Here's a quote from my textbook:

> Although reallocating an array is an O(n) operation, it is amortized over n items, so the cost per item is O(1).

I can't find a clear definition for what amortized means in this context.

Comment: Cost over time, same definition as the dictionary.